# Generate sysprep unattend.xml After Run

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sysprep

Is there a way to generate the `unattend.xml` file after running `sysprep` manually?

I would like the just automate the processes of running sysprep oobe non-generalized restart without having to accept the license and changing the admin password.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the generation `unatend.xml` during installation Windows Server or on the basis of an existing installation, then this is not possible.

There tool named [Windows System Image Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd744394(v=ws.10).aspx) that helps propertly create `unattend.xml` - it's part of [Microsoft Deployment Kit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dn475741.aspx).

Settings which you must provide to skip oobe described in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/settings-for-automating-oobe).

Comment: I have a vm template that we clone and just run sysprep after the clone. When we run sysprep after the clone the prompt that appears is to accept the license and enter in the administrator's password. I was hoping that I would be able to automate these two steps with an unattend.xml

Comment: Is it VMWare?  If so, why not use the Customization Manager to create a customized deploy that does the sysprep for you?